# Soql put inside where clause not working, but works alone

Tags: soql

I am trying the below SOQL, for some reason it doesn't work. I tried the SOQL inside where clause alone that works,

```
select Id,Name from Offer__c where Id in (select Offer_Id__c from Segment_Offers__c where Segment_Id__c ='a2n17000000EhO7AAK' order by Offer_Priority__c ASC LIMIT 4)
```

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work_ ? Do you  get an error or just no records ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOQL is not the same as SQL and does not support much in the way of expressions in the right-hand side of a "[fieldExpression](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm)". It does, as Derek F points out in the comments, have some semi-join and anti-join capability using "IN (SELECT ...)" or "NOT IN (SELECT ...). However, this only works in specific scenarios.

Some options you have here are:

1. To execute the queries separately and generate a binding variable to substitute the Id match options.
2. To change the query to select the data a different way.
3. To ensure you align with supported [SOQL semi-join capabilities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm)

In this case, applying option 2, perhaps you could use:

```
SELECT Offer_Id__c, Offer_Id__r.Name
    FROM Segment_Offers__c
    WHERE Segment_Id__c = :id
    ORDER BY Offer_Priority__c ASC LIMIT 4
```

(Always best to use a binding for a value like an ID and to obtain that dynamically rather than hard-coding the value, which can change from org to org.)

In this case you simply need to fetch the name values through the returned `Offer_Id__r.Name` and either `Offer_Id__c` or `Offer_Id__r.Id` values.

Comment: The `WHERE <id field> IN (<subquery>)` pattern is supported by SOQL. It's called a semi-join (or anti-join if you use `NOT IN`). It's covered in the second section of [SOQL comparison operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm)

Comment: This is only for directly related parent/child though, right? Here the relationship is not being used in an appropriate way from what I can see.

Comment: BTW, happy to delete my answer if you have a better one.

Comment: Thanks @Phil W your query works. but still have no idea why mine didn't work. I have seen that usage everywhere on the internet. It says error parsing query. But for the time being I am happy and can continue with my work. Thanks again.